# Undefined type 'Mpdf\Mpdf' in Laravel 7.2.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, mpdf

Please help me because I'm not able to create a PDF in Laravel 7.2.5 .
My mPDF version ^6.1 . When i'm writing `$mpdf= new \Mpdf\Mpdf();` , throws an error as image below :

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUrXU.png)

Error in localhost :

[error localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZVz8.png)

Comment: have you added the package to your project using composer?  $ composer require mpdf/mpdf

Comment: try ```new Mpdf\Mpdf() ``` instead and don't forget to add ```require_once("vendor/autoload.php"); ``` at the top of your php file

Comment: added `require_once("vendor/autoload.php");` and `new Mpdf\Mpdf()` , but not working :( . i also added `use \Mpdf`

Comment: when i run composer dumpautoload mPDF not discover within discovered packages

Comment: Try looking for mpdf pachage in your vendor, if it exists, and look how the class was named

Comment: @ElvinMəmmədov try running composer update and make sure that mpdf is listed in your composer.json file

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved, the error message (both in text form!), and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

See the note on the documentation page.

> Note: For mPDF < 7.0 use

```
<?php

$mpdf = new \mPDF();
```

Dokumentation:  https://mpdf.github.io/getting-started/creating-your-first-file.html